# Как выбрать месяц, год и число?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой компонент можно использовать для выбора месяца, года, даты ОТДЕЛЬНО? Т.е. год, месяц и дата должны выбираться в отдельных компонентах, типа `combobox`.

Comment: А чем не устраивают три комбобокса?

Answer (score 1):

1. Кнопки.
2. ComboBox
3. RadioButton (в зависимости от целей)